# What is the problem with my named group in this regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I am working on trying to locate some registration numbers in some documents.  The best tool for this seems to be Pythons re module.  I have created a regular expression that works but I am not able to make this work when I move to a named group.

Here is the original text I am trying to extract from

```
    REGISTRATION NO.  874224207             PAGE 32
```

This regular expression works on Pythex

```
\s+\(?\s*REGISTRATION\s+NUMBER\)?[\.:]?\)?\s+[A-Z0-9#]{9}\s+|\s+\(?\s*REGISTRATION\s+NO\)?[\.:]?\)?\s+[A-Z0-9#]{9}\s+
```

But when I name my capture group theregis - that is all I want from the result I am not showing any match

```
\s+\(?\s*REGISTRATION\s+NUMBER\)?[\.:]?\)?\s+(?P<theregis>[A-Z0-9#]{9})\s+|\s+\(?\s*REGISTRATION\s+NO\)?[\.:]?\)?\s+(?P=theregis)\s+
```

Per the docs

1. My named group is in parens
2. I begin my group with a ?P
3. My group has a name that is enclosed with <>

When I use my named group

1. The group is placed in ()
   2  I begin with a ? and then P=
2. The group name matched the name I gave it
3. There are no extraneous characters in the parens where I have used the group name
4. I tried changing the group name to something else - no luck

Finally - I used this as my model

```
 p = re.compile(r'\b(?P<word>\w+)\s+(?P=word)\b')
```

Comment: You are trying to recurse the `threregis` pattern, but `(?P=theregis)` is a *backreference* that "repeats" the *text* captured into that group. You need to use `(?&theregis)` but only with PyPi *`regex`* module that supports recursion in the same way PCRE does.

Comment: Since I don't understand your observation about me trying to recurse the pattern I guess this loses me.  I am trying to not have to retype the pattern and understand how to use named groups.  I am trying to do something much more complicated with a pattern and decided that learning to use named groups would be helpful to my goals.  I made this example because I was not successful and decided to simplify things as much as possible

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do, and it is exactly what you can't do with `re`, but you can do it with `regex`, as [shown here](https://regex101.com/r/ElyNfD/1). Or build the pattern dynamically.

Comment: Are you saying that the named group can't be used on the other side of the pipe?  Sorry for such a simplistic question

Comment: No, I said you cannot re-use the named capturing group pattern by means of a named group backreference. There are other ways for it, even when using `re`, see the linked thread.